# SABRE BFM Eurostar search, no results for standard premier & business premier classes

Tags: sabre

We're using Sabre's Rest BFM Api. We can search for Eurostar tickets in standard class. However, searching for either Standard Premier or Business Premier never returns any results.

```
{
  "Target": "Production",
  "POS": {
    "Source": [
      {
        "PseudoCityCode": "",
        "RequestorID": {
          "Type": "1",
          "ID": "",
          "CompanyName": {

          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "OriginDestinationInformation": [
    {
      "RPH": "1",
      "DepartureDateTime": "2019-07-17T00:00:00",
      "OriginLocation": {
        "LocationCode": "QQS"
      },
      "DestinationLocation": {
        "LocationCode": "XPG"
      },
      "TPA_Extensions": {
        "SegmentType": {
          "Code": "O"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "TravelPreferences": {
    "ValidInterlineTicket": true,
    "CabinPref": [
      {
        "Cabin": "Z",
        "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
      }
    ],
    "TPA_Extensions": {
      "TripType": {
        "Value": "Return"
      },
      "LongConnectTime": {
        "Min": 780,
        "Max": 1200,
        "Enable": true
      },
      "ExcludeCallDirectCarriers": {
        "Enabled": false
      }
    }
  },
  "TravelerInfoSummary": {
    "SeatsRequested": [
      1
    ],
    "AirTravelerAvail": [
      {
        "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
          {
            "Code": "ADT",
            "Quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "TPA_Extensions": {
    "IntelliSellTransaction": {
      "RequestType": {
        "Name": "50ITINS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We're not receiving any results, nor an any error messages. I have tried to contact Sabre, but I'm yet to receive a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its due to

```
 "CabinPref": [
      {
        "Cabin": "Z",
        "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
      }
```

Have you looked up the cabin code in the RBD for the "carrier"?

And why have you specified that this is a return trip if you only specify 1 RPH?